# Convert Aura cmp.set() to LWC equivalent

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm fairly new to LWC and I'm having trouble determining an effective way to convert something like this:

```
handleInputChanges : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fieldName1 = event.getSource().get("v.fieldName");

        component.set("v.ticket." + fieldName1, fieldValue);
}
```

into LWC. I've tried these and none of them have worked. I get an error that's along the lines of " [Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object String]']" or  "[Cannot add property Subject__c, object is not extensible]"

```
    handleInputChange(event) {
        console.log('*** handleInputChange: ' + JSON.stringify(event.currentTarget.dataset.id) + ' value: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        const fieldName = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const value = event.detail.value;
        const fieldValuePair = {fieldName , value};
        
        //none of these work
        this.opsTicket[fieldName] = value;

        this.opsTicket = Object.assign(fieldName, value);

        this.opsTicket.fields[fieldName] = value;

        let tempOpsTicket = this.opsTicket;
        tempOpsTicket = Object.assign(fieldName, value);

        this.opsTicket.push(fieldValuePair);
    }
```

opsTicket is a custom object record that's initialized from the controller. Here's how I initialize it from the lwc controller (trimmed down):

```
    initTicket() {
        console.log('*** initOpsTicket');


        initOpsTicket({application: this.application, requestType: this.requestType})
        .then(result => {
            console.log('*** init success');
            this.response = result;
            this.opsTicket = this.response.opsTicket;           
        })
        .catch(error => {           
            console.log('*** error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
```

In apex (trimmed down version) it's this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Response initOpsTicket(String application, String requestType) {      

        Response response = new Response();

        try {
                Operations_Support_Ticket__c ost = new Operations_Support_Ticket__c(OwnerId = queue.Id, Operations_Route__c = opsRoutes[0].Id, Application__c = application, Request_Type__c = requestType);
                response.opsTicket = ost;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            response.success = false;
            system.debug('ERROR at Row # ' + e.getLineNumber() + ': ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;        
    }
```

I think I can write something into my controller to handle the record update, but it seems... excessive? Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: This question is not quite the same as this related question [How to modify a wired result in a getter?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320958/how-to-modify-a-wired-result-in-a-getter). This question is asking how to achieve an equivalent without resorting to an apex controller method. The related question provides guidance on the record being read-only (answers why the error), but doesn't provide an answer how to clone the object nor how to dynamically add properties to the cloned object.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show how you declared and initialized `opsTicket`. If it is initialized from the response of a wire or imperative call, as you seem to say, it will be read only. You must clone the response to make it editable client side.

Comment: Question edited as requested. I'm calling the init imperatively as there's some detail that needs to be set by the user first before I do that action. This approach is the same as what I previously used in aura with success. The article doesn't answer the question as I'm trying to take a shell that's' initialized and dynamically append fields & values depending on some other context established during the init.

Comment: The data you get back from any wire or imperative is **read only**. You cannot add other properties to it etc. That is why the other answer **is** the answer to your problem. This is how LWCs behave.

Comment: I'm unsure how I can apply your answer to this. In my scenario the field names aren't known (hard coded) and are bound to the input field. I know I can pass my response var back over to my apex controller with the field/value via another imperative apex call. I'm just not sure that's the right way to take advantage of lwc.

Comment: If you need to modify the result, rather than use a wrapper, clone it on receipt. You have various different options for doing that cloning. Take a look [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-clone-a-javascript-object.html).

Comment: That helps. Seems I was close with the let tempOpsTicket route, but it needed to be `let tempOpsTicket = Object.assign({}, this.opsTicket);` for it to clone correctly. Thank you. I'll post working example as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With [Phil W](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50252/phil-w)'s help, here is my modified code that will dynamically place field values from an input where the field API name is retrieved from the event.

As Phil mentioned, data pulled back via a wire or imperative loading is read-only and new properties cannot be added. Instead of using a wrapper, I cloned the variable on receipt via `Object.assign({}, this.myObject)` so that I could add new properties as needed.

```
initTicket() {
        console.log('*** initOpsTicket');

        initOpsTicket({application: this.application, requestType: this.requestType})
        .then(result => {
            this.response = result;
            //clone the inbound record from the controller so it can be manipulated
            this.opsTicket = Object.assign({}, this.response.opsTicket);            
        })
        .catch(error => {           
            console.log('*** error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
```

```
<lightning-input data-id="Subject__c" type="text" label="Subject" required onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
```

```
    handleInputChange(event) {
        console.log('*** handleInputChange: ' + JSON.stringify(event.currentTarget.dataset.id) + ' value: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        const fieldName = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const value = event.detail.value;

        this.opsTicket[fieldName] = value;
        console.log('*** tempOpsTicket: ' + JSON.stringify(this.opsTicket));
    }
```

Helpful Resources:

- https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-clone-a-javascript-object.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex

> IMPORTANT Assume that Apex methods provision immutable data, even if it's possible to mutate the data today. It's a best practice to treat all data that a component receives as immutable. To mutate the data, make a shallow copy of the objects you want to mutate. It’s important to understand this concept when working with data. See Data Flow.